# viewport tag not working on some devices, page shows up too wide

Tags: html, ios, iphone, viewport, responsive

http://hydramovie.com/

I'm having trouble with this website rendering too wide, so far I've only been able to see the problem on my clients iphone 4, and also on his wife's iphone 6, I've had no problems on my iphone 5s. I've run it through a bunch of emulators online and have not been able to re-create the clients issues.

[image: screenshot of buggy mobile website]

The screenshot shows the gallery section opening up too wide for the screen.

Does anyone have any advice for troubleshooting a problem which so far only the client can see on his mobile devices. Please let me know if I should post any specific code for further information.